# How can I prevent 'staff' from deleting models in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a team members and make them able to manage admin sites. But I want to give them permission only for `add, change`(not `delete`) models in `admin` site.

What I tried is below:

1. Make them `staff` (Not `Superuser`)
   [image]
2. Give them only `add, change` pemissions.
   [image]

However, this user is able to delete models in `admin` site!

What's wrong with my setting?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Group` named `mygroup`. Choose all permissions and remove whatever you dont need.

[image: create group]
Edit `User`object like

- remove `superuser` status
- select the group as `mygroup`
  [image: edit user]

Now that user cannot see `delete` button.

Comment: Thanks. But what's wrong with my method(directly choosing permission)? Do I have to always create group for the permission?

Comment: First of all, it will prevent deletion only from admin.

Comment: What is 'it'? Groups?

Comment: that user who dont have `delete permission`

Comment: You mean, `Groups` affects only to `admin` page and `permission` affects to whole sites(application, admin, etc)?

Comment: This does not work. I don't think this is even a legit solution.